# JavaScript: clicked link should disappear in a spectacular way

Tags: javascript, css, unobtrusive-javascript

I've programmed a PHP/PostgreSQL/Oracle script for internal usage at my work, where links are displayed as light-blue "tags", which can also be hidden by clicking an "x" near them:

[image]

This works pretty well sofar and my colleagues are already impressed.

The CSS-appearance for the "tags" I have stolen from Stackoverflow (since my own CSS/JS skills are very limited and also *Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery*):

```
a.hide {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.hide:hover {
        background-color: #e7540c;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #A33B08;
        border-right: 1px solid #A33B08;
        text-decoration: none;
}

a.tag {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.tag:hover {
        background-color: #3E6D8E;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
        border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now I would like to enhance my script by few JavaScript lines and **make the "tags" disappear in an interesting way, when an "x" near them has been clicked by the user** (the links should still work of course). Maybe make them fly up or maybe even explode? Does anybody have an idea here or can share a nice trick?

I'd prefer not to use jQuery, because I haven't learnt it yet.

Thank you and I hope for your creativity :-)
Alex

Comment: this will probably further impress your colleagues http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode

Comment: That one is cool, thanks! I hope more answers will come though... (because I still feel bad for including jQuery just for 1 effect).

Comment: Two of your statements are at odds - *since my own CSS/JS skills are very limited* and *I'd prefer not to use jQuery, because I haven't learnt it yet.* - if you're still learning JS, jQuery has a shallower learning curve, and will help you avoid lots of common JS headaches. If you were already proficient or an expert JS coder, then perhaps jQuery wouldn't be useful for this task. If I were you I would prefer jQuery solutions.

Comment: And also I wonder if my link will still work with that jQuery explosion effect and how to apply it to the "tag", when an "x" (i.e. not the same element) is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure javascript fadeout effect would be (*for non-IE browsers at the moment..*)

```
var hides = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

for (var i = 0 ; i < hides.length; i++)
{
    hides[i].onclick = function(evt){
        var el = this.parentNode;
        el.style.opacity=1;
        var el_timeout = setInterval(function(){
            el.style.opacity -= 0.05;
            console.log(el.style.opacity);
          if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05)
          {
              el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
              clearInterval(el_timeout);
          }
        },20);
    }
}
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/AkA5C/

I have wrapped the tag and button in a `<span></span>` so that you can easily target both.

Comment: Awesome answer and jsfiddle.net seems to be a nice tool

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). Easy as hell and looks cool

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he'd prefer not using jQuery.

Comment: But JQuery is the way to go. I vote on get with the times and USE IT!

Answer (score 0):

I advise not using flamboyant “explosive” effects in your app, at the end of the day users are use your app because it solves a problem not to get a show.  If you must have effects, then use simple effects.  If you MUST use such effects then use a different technology like flash.

Comment: Ok, good point here. A fade out effect would be nice and unobtrusive. I "must not" use any effects, but my script already has a "web 2.0" look, since I display links as "tags". So I think adding a small effect would be suitable here.

Comment: "If you must have effects, then use simple effects", that would include fade ins/outs etc...